# Split react router to different div

Tags: reactjs

```
function LoginPage(){
  return(
    <div>
    <h1>Loginpage</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function Header(){
  return(
    <div>
      <Router>
      <div className="header">
        <div className="logo">
          <NavLink to="/">Frd</NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="navBar">
        <NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/"></Route>
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}></Route>
        </Switch>
         </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to make the LoginPage component not rendered right after 'Login' link? i don't what the LoginPage component rendered in 'header' div, i tried to split the `Switch` to 'content' div but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can simply put the switch down outside of the `header` div in it's own div like this:

```
// ...
<div>
  <Router>
    <div className="header">
      <div className="logo">
        <NavLink to="/">Frd</NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className="navBar">
        <NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="body">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/"></Route>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
</div>
// ...
```